# How to create lambda-wrapper around C-style callback?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, lambda, c++-cli

I have such layers: C# main application -- CLI/C++ wrapper for C++ library -- C++ library.

CLI middle layer was written because of the limitations of C#-C++ interoperability. I used it also to polish some rough edges from C# point of view -- in other words, the middle layer allows to hide C/C++ types (like `char*`) and do all necessary conversions.

One conversion I fail to make is passing a callback. I tried to do it as in [Pass a c++ lambda to old c function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746048/pass-a-c-lambda-to-old-c-function-pointer) but I cannot pass a lambda as a callback.

C++ callback definition:

```
typedef void (*CppOnEngineCloseCallback)
    (void * customParam, const wchar_t * errorMessage);
```

I know `customParam` is not used, so I define such callback for middle layer (CLI/C++):

```
typedef void (*CLIOnEngineCloseCallback)
        ( String ^ errorMessage);
```

In the wrapper I create such lambda:

```
// lambda signature should resemble CppOnEngineCloseCallback
auto lambda = [&] (void * customParam, const wchar_t * errorMessage) {
    cli_callback(Marshal::PtrToStringUni( IntPtr(static_cast<void*>(
        const_cast<wchar_t*>(errorMessage)))));
};
```

My concern is if `cli_callback` will be properly kept in CLI environment (this is my first project) -- after all, I pass it in time A, and use it in time B.

Compiler has even stronger concern, because when I try to use the lambda:

```
InitEngine( // C++ function that requires callback
    &lambda);
```

it says it cannot convert `lambda` into `CppOnEngineCloseCallback`.

Is it doable in the first place? How?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `auto`, hence you're hiding the actual type, and making it harder on yourself to manage the C++ strongly typed type safety.

Probably the lambda function isn't the right type, or at least not the type you're expecting.

`CppOnEngineCloseCallback` is probably a function pointer type (or std::funciton type).
So, to help yourself, try changing the `lambda`'s type to the expected type, and see what the compiler says.

```
CppOnEngineCloseCallback lambda = [&] (void * customParam, const wchar_t * errorMessage) {
    cli_callback(Marshal::PtrToStringUni( IntPtr(static_cast<void*>(
        const_cast<wchar_t*>(errorMessage)))));
};
```

The `InitEngine()` method expects a `CppOnEngineCloseCallback`, so you must make sure it gets it.

Besides that, you can only assign a lambda with empty brackets `[]` to a function pointer. In your case you're not using anything from the local scope, hence you don't really need `[&]`.

[Lambda functions : operator ret(*)(params)()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

> This user-defined conversion function is only defined if the capture
>   list of the lambda-expression is empty.

If you do want to use this kind of lambda expression, you'll have to use std::function instead of a function pointer:

```
typedef std::function<void(void *, const wchar_t *)> CppOnEngineCloseCallback;
```

Comment: Thank you. `CppOnEngineCloseCallback` is a function pointer as shown in my question (first snippet). Changing `auto` to `CppOnEngineCloseCallback` only moves the error (message is exactly the same) to the line with `lambda` definition.

Comment: @greenoldman I've edited my answer to explain how you can use `[]` instead of `[&]`. Or use `std::function` instead

Comment: Thank you again, but `cli_callback` sits in local scope and I need to capture it. When I specify only it for capturing I get back to original error. And I cannot modify C++ layer (the one of the library), only CLI/C++ and C#.

Comment: @greenoldman Then you can define a proper method instead of a lambda and make cli_callback accessable.

Comment: But  theoretically what you're doing IS possible, and once you get the compilation errors fixed you just need to make the right parameters accessible,

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is not possible, to cast a lambda to a function pointer.
As you know, a lambda is an object of a compiler generated class, that only behaves like a function.

For your actual problem: you mentioned that `customParam` is not used.

A typical pattern is, that `customParam` is provided by the caller of the library and used in the callback function to identify some object handling the callback. Inside the callback, you then map to the function you actually want to call:

```cpp
void MyNativeCallback(void * customParam, const wchar_t * errorMessage)
{
    static_cast<MyClass*>(customParam)->Callback(errorMessage);
}
```

So you could pass a pointer to your lambda as customParam to the library, and provide a helper function as above as callback. Anyways, getting the pointer types correctly will not be a simple task. I would prefer a small helper class instead.